# Angular ui-router passing data between subviews of the same state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How do I access other subviews in the same state. I am building a page with a toolbar on top and a sidebar and I want a button on the toolbar to open/close the sidebar and buttons in the sidebar to change the content. easy of it's all in the same controller but what I did is to use ui-router's subview feature like this:

```
.state('dash', {
    url: '/dash/:id',
    views: {
      nav: {
        controller: 'NavCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        templateUrl: '/views/navbar.html'
      },
      sidebar: {
        controller: 'SidebarCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        templateUrl: '/views/sidebar.html'
      },
      content: {
        controller: 'DashCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        templateUrl: '/views/dash.html'
      }
    }
  })
```

UI looks like this:

[image]

Comment: if you'd name your controllers differently with controller as, you could use the NavCtrl in the sidebarCtrl's template. Maybe use some boolean value that exists on the NavCtrl, that decides what to show in the sidebar?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Define a resolve and use it as a place to store common data for the activated 'dash' state.

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('dash', {
    url: '/',
    resolve: { 
      dashData: function() { 
        return { input: "default value" }; 
      } 
    },
    views: {
      nav: {
        controller: function() {

        },
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        template: '<h3>This is the Navbar</h3>'
      },
      sidebar: {  
        controller: function(dashData) { // Inject reference to resolve object
          this.dashData = dashData; 
        },
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        template: 'content data visible in ' + 
                     'the sidebar: <b>{{ ctrl.dashData.input }}<b>'
      },
      content: {
        controller: function(dashData) { // Inject reference to resolve object
          this.dashData = dashData;
        },
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.dashData.input">' + 
                  'This is bound to dashData.input'
      }
    }
  })
});
```

Inject the shared object into each controller

```
app.controller('DashCtrl', function(dashData, $scope) {
  $scope.dashData = dashData;
});
app.controller('... ....
```

I put this example in a plunker for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/8M1zXN0W5ybiB8KyxvqW?p=preview

Comment: I did not know I can pass data to resolve and read it from resolve. Been trying to understand how to no avail. Do you mind expanding a little on your idea?

Comment: I updated the answer, showing how to pass in the resolve, binding it to multiple child view controllers, and updating/showing the bound data in the views.

Comment: I think this (or I) is still missing something `<input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.dashData.input">` updates `$scope.dashData` not the shared variable.

Comment: @Mika I added a link to a plunker

Answer (score 5):

This would be a good example of where an abstract parent state comes in handy:

> An abstract state can have child states but can not get activated itself. An 'abstract' state is simply a state that can't be transitioned to. It is activated implicitly when one of its descendants are activated.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views#abstract-states

And then especially this usecase:

> inherit $scope objects down to children

Consider the following abstract parent state and it's child state:

```
$stateProvider.state('root', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/dash',
    templateUrl: 'root.html',
    controller: 'rootController'
});

$stateProvider.state('dash', {
    parent: 'root',
    url: '/:id',
    views: {
        'navbar': {
            templateUrl: 'navbar.html',
            controller: 'navbarController'
        },
        'sidebar': {
            templateUrl: 'sidebar.html',
            controller: 'sidebarController'
        },
        'content': {
            templateUrl: 'content.html',
            controller: 'contentController'
        }
    }
});
```

Now you can store logic (and data) you need in your childstate in the controller of the abstract parent state:

```
angular.module('app').controller('rootController', [
             '$scope',
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.sidebar = {
            show: true
        };
        $scope.items = [{
            name: 'Alpha'
        }, {
            name: 'Bravo'
        },{
            name: 'Charlie'
        },{
            name: 'Delta'
        }];
        $scope.selected = $scope.items[0];
        $scope.select = function (item) {
            $scope.selected = item;
        }
    }
]);
```

Example of using this logic/data in a template of the child state, sidebar.html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" role="presentation">
        <a href="#" ng-click="select(item)">{{item.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here's a complete example with your requirements, i could post all the code here but i think that would be a bit too much:

http://embed.plnkr.co/2jKJtFM0GWsylyLcAdne/

I'll gladly answer any question you may have, just holler. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I will follow your advice and use an abstract state but I awarded the bounty Chris because he actually answers the question without any structural changes.

Answer (score 1):

if you'd name your controllers differently with controller as, you could use the NavCtrl in the sidebarCtrl's template. Maybe use some boolean value that exists on the NavCtrl, that decides what to show in the sidebar? (from the comment)

This should work, haven't tried it though.

```
.state('dash', {
        url: '/dash/:id',
        views: {
          nav: {
            controller: 'NavCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'navCtrl',
            templateUrl: '/views/navbar.html'
          },
          sidebar: {
            controller: 'SidebarCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'sidebarCtrl',
            templateUrl: '/views/sidebar.html'
          },
          content: {
            controller: 'DashCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'dashCtrl',
            templateUrl: '/views/dash.html'
          }
        }
      })
```

sidebarService:

```
angular.module('app').value('sidebarService', {show: true});
```

navCtrl something like this:

```
function(sidebarService){
  var vm = this;
  vm.toggleSideBar = function(){sidebarService.show = !sidebarService.show;}//used in navbar.html
}
```

sidebarCtrl:

```
function(sidebarService){
  var vm = this;
  vm.showSideBar= sidebarService;
}
```

and then in sidebar.html you use the sidebar value service:

```
<div ng-if="sidebarCtrl.showSideBar.show">
<!--SideBar-->
</div
```

Comment: I tried that but I can't access other controllers from the none corresponding html. In `sidebar.html` `{{navCtrl.showSidebar}}` returns nothing. IDE says "unresolved variable navCtrl".

Comment: yeah, you're right. Maybe because they are sibling scopes I guess..., but then why not use some value-service to store the boolean?

Comment: I think that is not as clean as finding a good way to have the controllers communicate.

Comment: Also I simplified my question but the next step is influencing the content based on changes in the sidebar. That would require more services.

Comment: Maybe you should consider having them in sub-states? otherwise communication between sibling controllers I guess you either have to use a service like in my updated answer or some event communication by $emiting to the parent controller and then $broadcasting down to the other children

Comment: How would you organise the children states? The sidebar, content, and topbars would still be at the same level.

Comment: But doesn't it sound like you could have the top as parent to side, which is parent to content? If interaction with top changes side, and interaction with side changes content doesn't this structure make sense?

Comment: I need to think about how to set that up... lol such a pain to change languages...

Answer (score 1):

You can use events to communicate between controllers. Check the AngularJS documentation for `$scope.$broadcast` and `$scope.$on : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope